# Get document dimensions with body.height = 0px

Tags: javascript, html, dom, document

How can I get the documents dimensions (width and height) if the 'body' element has css style applied to it:

```
body {
 height: 0px;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "document"? Do you mean the `html` element, since that actually defines an HTML document? What research have you done and what attempts have you made?

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple approach

```
document.body.style.height // returns '0px'
```